# Inconsistent movement in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to built psuedo-galaga and I want consistent movement of my JComponents. They are laid out in a null layout, custom JPanel within a custom JFrame container. When I move my character, the speed of the bullets changes - by using the timer I am trying to limit the frame rate so that they move consistently but that has not worked.

Why does my code slow down when the user is moving? I feel like it is a focus subsystem issue or that I should maybe be using multiple threads?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    private Dimension dimension;
    private final int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
    private JPanel screen;
    public Frame(int width, int height) {
        WIDTH = width;
        HEIGHT = height;
        dimension = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setMinimumSize(dimension);
        this.setMaximumSize(dimension);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("Galaga");
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setForeground(Color.white);
        screen = new LevelOneScreen(dimension);
        this.getContentPane().add(screen);
        screen.requestFocus();
        screen.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void display() {
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
        if(screen instanceof LevelOneScreen && ((LevelOneScreen) screen).isDone()) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LevelOneScreen extends JPanel {
    public static ArrayList<LevelOneBullet> enemyBullets;
    private ArrayList<LevelOneEnemy> enemies;
    private boolean direction;
    private Dimension dimension;
    private User user;
    private int score;
    private boolean isDone;

    public LevelOneScreen(Dimension dimension) {
        this.dimension = dimension;
        isDone = false;
        enemies = new ArrayList<LevelOneEnemy>();
        enemyBullets = new ArrayList<LevelOneBullet>();
        direction = true;
        this.setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        createEnemies();
        createUser();
        user.requestFocusInWindow();
        user.requestFocus();
        score = 0;
        this.setSize(dimension);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createUser() {
        user = new User((int) (dimension.getWidth() / 2), (int) (dimension.getHeight() - 100));
        user.setVisible(true);
        this.add(user);
    }

    private void createEnemies() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("Enemy1.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Reading \"Enemy1.png\"");
        }
        // dimension.width
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            enemies.add(new LevelOneEnemy(i * 40 + 5, 30, img));
            enemies.get(i).setVisible(true);
        }
        for (LevelOneEnemy e : enemies) {
            this.add(e);
        }
    }

    private void paintEnemies(Graphics g) {
        for (LevelOneEnemy e : enemies) {
            e.paint(g);
            if (!direction)
                e.setLocation(e.getX() - 1, e.getY());
            else
                e.setLocation(e.getX() + 1, e.getY());
        }
        if (enemies.get(enemies.size() - 1).getX() + 45 > dimension.getWidth() && direction) {
            direction = false;
        } else if (enemies.get(0).getX() < 5 && !direction) {
            direction = true;
        }
    }

    private void paintCollisionObjects(Graphics g) {
        if (!enemies.isEmpty()) {
            paintEnemies(g);
            // check for bullet collision
            if (!user.getBullets().isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = enemies.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    for (int j = user.getBullets().size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                        if (enemies.get(i).getBounds().intersects(user.getBullets().get(j).getBounds())) {
                            this.remove(enemies.get(i));
                            enemies.remove(i);
                            user.getBullets().remove(j);
                            score += 100;
                            // To prevent ArrayOutOfBoundsException when
                            // Enemies are destroyed faster than they're removed
                            if (enemies.size() == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // check for user collision
            if (!enemies.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = enemies.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (enemies.get(i).getBounds().intersects(user.getBounds())) {
                        enemies.get(i).setLocation(0, getParent().getHeight() + 100);
                        this.remove(enemies.get(i));
                        enemies.remove(i);
                        user.decrementHealth();
                        score += 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!enemyBullets.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = enemyBullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    enemyBullets.get(i).paint(g);
                    if (enemyBullets.get(i).getY() > getParent().getHeight() + 50) {
                        enemyBullets.remove(i);
                    } else if (enemyBullets.get(i).getBounds().intersects(user.getBounds())) {
                        enemyBullets.remove(i);
                        user.decrementHealth();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        user.paintComponent(g);
        paintCollisionObjects(g);
        if(!isDone && enemies.isEmpty())
            isDone = true;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return isDone;
    }
    
    public boolean isDead() {
        return user.healthPercent() < .1;
    }
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    
    public double getHealth() {
        return user.healthPercent();
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Level One Screen\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            s = s + this.getComponent(i) + "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LevelOneBullet extends JComponent {
    private Image img;
    private int dy;
    public LevelOneBullet(int x, int y, boolean isEnemy) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            if(isEnemy)
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("EnemyLaserShot.png"));
            else
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("UserLaserShot.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(isEnemy)
                System.out.println("Error Reading \"EnemyLaserShot.png\"");
            else
                System.out.println("Error Reading \"UserLaserShot.png\"");
        }
        this.img = img;
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(x, y, 16, 30);
        dy = isEnemy ? 3 : -3;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, super.getX(), super.getY(), 16, 30, null);
        //super.setLocation(super.getX(), super.getY() + dy);
        this.setBounds(super.getX(), super.getY()+dy, 16, 30);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "LevelOneBullet: @" + super.getX() + ", " +super.getY();
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LevelOneEnemy extends JComponent {
    private Image im;
    private int health;
    private int shootSeed;
    private long time;
    private long lastTimeFired;
    public LevelOneEnemy(int x, int y, Image im, int health) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        super.setBounds(x, y, 30, 30);
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        this.im = im;
        this.health = health;
        shootSeed = rand.nextInt(1000)+5000;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastTimeFired = 0;
    }

    public LevelOneEnemy(int x, int y, Image im) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        super.setBounds(x, y, 30, 30);
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        this.im = im;
        this.health = 100;
        shootSeed = rand.nextInt(1000)+6000;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastTimeFired = 0;
    }
    public LevelOneEnemy(int x, int y, Image im, boolean isLevelOne) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        super.setBounds(x, y, 30, 30);
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        this.im = im;
        this.health = 100;
        shootSeed = rand.nextInt(1000)+6000;
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastTimeFired = 0;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if((System.currentTimeMillis()-time) % shootSeed < (shootSeed/30) &&
                System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeFired > 5000) {
                LevelOneScreen.enemyBullets.add(new LevelOneBullet(this.getX()+15, this.getY()+10, true));
            lastTimeFired = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        g.drawImage(im, super.getX(), super.getY(), 30, 30, null);
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "LevelOneEnemy @(" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Runner {
    public final static int SCREENHEIGHT = 1000;
    public final static int SCREENWIDTH = 800;
    private static Frame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new Frame(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);
        FrameRateListener listen = new FrameRateListener();
        Timer timer = new Timer(34, listen);
        timer.start();
    }
    private static class FrameRateListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.display();
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserKeyboardListener implements KeyListener {
    private int dx, dy;
    private int shoot;
    private int speed;
    private ArrayList<Integer> keysPressed;

    public UserKeyboardListener() {
        keysPressed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        shoot = 0;
        speed = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public int getdx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public int getdy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public int getShoot() {
        return shoot;
    }

    public boolean decrementShoot() {
        if (shoot - 1 < 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            shoot = shoot - 1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        } else {
            if (!keysPressed.contains(key))
                keysPressed.add(key);
            if(keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_C))
                speed = 2;
            else
                speed = 1;
            if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
                dx = 0;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
                dx = 1*speed;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
                dx = -1*speed;
            } else {
                dx = 0;
            }
            if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP) && keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                dy = 0;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
                dy = -1*speed;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                dy = 1*speed;
            } else {
                dy = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            shoot++;
        } else {
            if (keysPressed.contains(key))
                keysPressed.remove(keysPressed.indexOf(key));
            if(keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_C))
                speed = 2;
            else
                speed = 1;
            if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
                dx = 0;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
                dx = 1*speed;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
                dx = -1*speed;
            } else {
                dx = 0;
            }
            if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP) && keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                dy = 0;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
                dy = -1*speed;
            } else if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                dy = 1*speed;
            } else {
                dy = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "UserKeyListener: (" + dx + ", " + dy + ")";
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class User extends JComponent {
    private Image im;
    private double health;
    private double initialHealth;
    private double healthDecrement;
    private double stamina;
    private int staminaDecrement;
    private long lastBulletFired;
    private ArrayList<LevelOneBullet> bullets;

    public User(int x, int y, double health) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("UserShip.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Reading \"UserShip.png\"");
        }
        bullets = new ArrayList<LevelOneBullet>();
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        super.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
        this.addKeyListener(new UserKeyboardListener());
        this.im = img;
        this.health = 100 * health;
        this.initialHealth = 100;
        this.healthDecrement = 100/5.0;
        this.stamina = 100;
        this.staminaDecrement = 10;
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public User(int x, int y) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("UserShip.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Reading \"UserShip.png\"");
        }
        bullets = new ArrayList<LevelOneBullet>();
        super.setLocation(x, y);
        super.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
        this.addKeyListener(new UserKeyboardListener());
        this.im = img;
        this.health = 100;
        this.initialHealth = 100;
        this.healthDecrement = health/5.0;
        this.stamina = 100;
        this.staminaDecrement = 10;
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        this.requestFocus();
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        
        if (this.getKeyListeners().length > 0 &&
                this.getKeyListeners()[0] instanceof UserKeyboardListener) {
            UserKeyboardListener listen = (UserKeyboardListener) this.getKeyListeners()[0];
            if(listen.getdx() != 0) {
                if(this.getX()+listen.getdx() + this.getWidth() < this.getParent().getWidth() &&
                        this.getX()+listen.getdx() > 5)
                    this.setLocation(this.getX() + listen.getdx(), this.getY());
                if(this.getX() < 10) {
                    this.setLocation(10, this.getY());
                }
                else if(this.getX()+this.getWidth() > this.getParent().getWidth() - 10)
                    this.setLocation(this.getParent().getWidth()-10-this.getWidth(), this.getY());
            }
            if(listen.getdy() != 0) {
                if(this.getY() + listen.getdy() > 30 && 
                        this.getY()+this.getHeight()+listen.getdy() < this.getParent().getHeight()-10)
                    this.setLocation(this.getX(), this.getY()+listen.getdy());
                if(this.getY() < 30) {
                    this.setLocation(30, this.getY());
                }
                else if(this.getY()+this.getHeight() > this.getParent().getHeight()-10)
                    this.setLocation(this.getX(), this.getParent().getHeight()-10-this.getHeight());
            }
            
            
            if (listen.getShoot() > 0 && stamina > 10) {
                bullets.add(new LevelOneBullet(super.getX() + 17, super.getY() - 5, false));
                decrementStamina();
                listen.decrementShoot();
                lastBulletFired = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        for (int i = bullets.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            bullets.get(i).paint(g);
            if (bullets.get(i).getY() < -50)
                bullets.remove(i);
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastBulletFired > 1000 && stamina < 100) {
            stamina += .5;
        }
        g.drawImage(im, super.getX(), super.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    }
    
    public double healthPercent() {
        return health/initialHealth;
    }
    
    public void decrementHealth() {
        health -= healthDecrement;
    }
    
    public double staminaPercent() {
        return stamina / 100.0;
    }
    
    public void decrementStamina() {
        stamina -= staminaDecrement;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "User: " + "(" + super.getX() + ", " + super.getY() + ")";
    }

    public ArrayList<LevelOneBullet> getBullets() {
        return bullets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, could I use a javax.Swing.Timer to control the repositioning of enemies and bullets?

Comment: The relevant code needs to be directly in your question.  If that github project goes away or changes, this question will be useless to future readers.

Comment: I'd suggest one drawing `JPanel` where you draw all your sprites and bullets as images.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) sections.

Comment: @VGR I put it in. Is there a way to attach image files?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc All of my sprites are drawn on a JPanel, "LevelOneScreen" extends JPanel. I've read through the "Creating a GUI..." documentation before, when I looked at SwingWorker though the docs said it could only be executed once so I wasn't sure how that would help me.

Comment: 1) *"I put it in."* [Edit] to add a [mre]. 2) `implements KeyListener` In Swing we'd typically use key bindings. 3) `new File("UserShip.png")` That won't work at the time of deployment, use `getResource("..")` for an URL that will. 4) `Frame extends JFrame` There is a  `Frame` class in AWT. So this name is confusing. Instead, give it a descriptive name like `GameFrame`. 5) *"when I looked at SwingWorker.."* No, @GilbertLeBlanc was instead referring to the Swing `Timer`, which is also mentioned in that section of the tutorial. 6) Test early and often. You should not be arriving here with ..

Comment: .. such large dumps of extremely poor code. 7) `paintComponent(Graphics g)` Any overridden paint method should immediately call the `super(..)` method. 8) `catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(..` Shorter and more useful (generally) is `e.printStackTrace();` 9) `new Frame(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT);` This is the wrong size, given it does not account for the frame decorations. Instead get the 'game play' component to return a suitable a suitable preferred size as a hint to the layout manager (the code should be using) then `pack()` the frame around it.

Comment: The problem is most likely that you’re changing your game state in your painting methods.  You don’t have control over when paintComponent is called;  the system decides that.  All sorts of user actions can trigger it:  moving the window, raising or lowering windows, screen savers, even just moving the mouse around.  Never change game state or object state in painting methods (except for painting-related objects like a Graphics instance).  Change that state in listeners, then call `repaint` to show the changes on the screen.

Comment: @VGR So would you do that within the Swing timer in the runner where the timer going off updates the positions and then calls `repaint()`? That would be the action that should trigger the update but the problem is there is no guarantee that the previous update finishes before the timer goes off again correct?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Would the `new File("UserShip.png");` not work even if this was packaged within a jar file?

Comment: By the time the image is packaged in a jar (which is basically a specific type of Zip archive), it would not work as it's no longer a file. But an URL (as returned by by `getResource(..)`) can refer to a `File` on the local disk, a resource within a Jar file, or a resource hot-linked off the internet. Basically, the URL is a lot more versatile than a file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson When you refer to the `super(..)` method in 7) you're talking about `super.paintComponent(g)` rather than `super.paint(g)` per the tutorial correct? Thanks for the note about the jar

Comment: *"you're talking about super.paintComponent(g) rather than super.paint(g) per the tutorial correct?"* Yes. An overridden `paintComponent` should use `super.paintComponent`, while for `paint` it would be `super.paint`. But stick to overriding `paintComponent` for a `JComponent` or any class that extends it.

Comment: Yep, yep just double checking because I don't use the other methods called by `paint()`

Comment: Yes, it is likely a game would update its state at regular intervals in the ActionListener of a Timer, then call `repaint` after changing that state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from what @VGR said, updating components position in the `paintComponents(..)` method. This should be done from another method that is called when the timer's action occurs. This then updates the positions of the JComponents based off of when they should be refreshed from the timer rather than when `paintComponents(..)` is called - which we do not have control over.